# TypeError: "issuerBaseURL" must be a valid uri in Next.js API route with auth0

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, auth0

Error image on the browser:

[image: Error image on the browser]

In the `pages/login.js` I have this:

```
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default function Index() {

    return (
      <div className='mt-28'>
         <a  href="/api/auth/logout">Logout</a>
         <a className='mt-28' href="/api/auth/login">login</a>
         
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and in `pages/api/auth/[...auth0].js` I have this:

```
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0'
 
export default handleAuth()
```

What is the solution, please?

Comment: Can you show us the `AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL` environment variables you have setup?

Comment: Follow this tutorial instructions https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/01-login#configure-the-sdk

Answer (score 0):

This happens becuase your AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL= in .evn.local is not set to https:// it should be

AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL='https:// your url '

Comment: What's strange is that I have the same problem but my AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL is properly set with the https:// protocol prefix.